# OS X Audio hiss/dropouts on recorded loopback audio

Tags: macos, audio-recording, loopback

I've been trying to achieve a desktop audio recording loopback setup like this one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AGc42kDiND8.
So far, all of my attempts produced audio recordings containing hiss/distortion that can be heard here: https://soundcloud.com/slava-syurin/osx-loopback-audio-hiss/s-FcAj0Pgg8J5?utm_source=clipboard&utm_medium=text&utm_campaign=social_sharing

You hear the same hiss regardless the nature of the audio that is being recorded. In this example, I recorded a guitar piece to avoid copyright. The same happens when for example trying to record desktop audio.

The computer is a 13" Macbook Pro 2020 M1 OSx Monterey 12.3.1
This has been attempted with 2 audio interfaces: a Behringer UMC 404 and a Audient iD44, although the issue shouldn't really be related to the outboard sound card.

Software wise, I have tried the following configurations:

- Blackhole (2ch or 16ch) with a multi-output device to hear the audio from osx
- Soundflower (similar setup to Blackhole)
- LadioCast (fed by an input from the Audient interface) into Blackhole or SWB Audio capture
  All of the above have been routed into OBS Studio or QuickTime player (audio record function) with the same results.

Despite trying different loopback drivers and recording software, each of the combination is giving me the same problem. Any idea of what may be causing it and/or how to fix it? Sounds like a sample rate issue or something, but I have been trying to tweak sample rates in Audio/Midi setup, all to no avail.

Help much appreciated!

Comment: I listened to your SoundCloud link on good headphones and I didn't hear what I would call a hiss (I think of a hiss as constant low-level white noise). The defect I heard, I would describe as more of a sprinkling of clicks or pops. Are we hearing the same thing? Also, what happens if you record 10 seconds of "silence" (Same recording setup, just don't play anything or say anything)? If the problematic artifacts show up on a recording that should be basically silent, post it so we can listen to it without the guitar in the way (that lets us crank up the volume to hear the noise better).

Comment: Anyway, my experience suggests those clicks are likely your Wi-Fi (or maybe Bluetooth) signals inducting into your analog audio lines. Try again with all your Wi-Fi and Bluetooth interfaces/devices turned off. Don't forget to power off your router and fully disable Wi-Fi and Bluetooth on your Mac, phone, watch, tablet, TV, keyboard, mouse, and anything else nearby with Wi-Fi or Bluetooth.